# Laravel won't delete/update a session

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I'm storing an array in a session variable and I have a function that removes an item from the array and I need to update the session however when I try unset() and then Session::set() it does not update and even calling Session::flush() is not clearing the session. I am able to access the array in the session I just can't update or delete it dynamically.

```
public static function removeFromCart($product_id)
{
    $key        =   'shopping_cart_items';
    $items      =   Session::get($key);
    $index      =   array_search($product_id, $items);
    unset($items[$index]);
    Session::set($key, $items); 
}
```

also tried forget() then set() which is called by the above function:

```
public static function refreshCartSession($items)
{
    $key    =   'shopping_cart_items';
    Session::forget($key);
    Session::set($key, $items);
}
```

In my controller when I dd() the Session::get($key) I can see that the particular item has been removed however when I reload the session appears to be back to the previous array and the changes I have made haven't had an effect:

```
    public function removeItemFromCart()
{
    $success_message    =   'Cart item has been removed.';
    $fail_message       =   'Failed to remove cart item.';
    $remove_key         =   'car_remove_item';
    if(Input::has($remove_key))
    {
        $item   =   Input::get($remove_key);
        ShopProducts::removeFromCart($item);
        return View::make('shop.shopcart')->with('cart_remove_success', dd(Session::get('shopping_cart_items')));      
    }
    else
        return View::make('shop.shopcart')->with('cart_remove_fail', $fail_message);
}
```

Comment: Why are you killing the script execution in that last code sample with `dd`? You need to return the view correctly so that the session is written properly when the framework runs through its cycle. Halting that cycle early will prevent the session from being written.

Comment: er that worked.. I was just dd() the session variable to see if the unset had removed it. I thought I had tested without the dd() but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

The session will be updated only if the whole request cycle occurs, so if you `dd('anything')` during the execution, the request will remain intact.